# Why not make it possible to accept 2 answers instead of 1?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In many occasions, one find more than one correct answer, or that 2 answers complete each others in such a way that both answer the question posted.

In such situations one tend to mark both of them as accepted answers, unfortunately the system is designed to allow only 1 accepted answer.

Can that be changed to allow 2 accepted answers instead of 1?

Comment: As this feature would affect the whole network it should be discussed on the mother meta. In fact, it already has been [discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable) many [times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/can-i-accept-two-answers).